# SHINY OUTPUT VARIABLE WITH IF STATEMENT IN RMARKDOWN

Tags: r, shiny, server, output, r-markdown

I am new to shiny and rmarkdown, I looked for some information on the internet but I cannot understand how to output a variable encompassing a if statement (or similarly a for statement) that is in shiny server into a different rmarkdown document.

For instance, in the following case I would like to print the variable output$price into rmarkdown in a code chunk after the "date", any suggestions?

Shiny code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage( 
  sidebarLayout( 
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("price","Price:", value = "", placeholder = "00.0"),
    ), 
    mainPanel(
      h5(textOutput("price")),
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session){  
  
  output$price <- renderText({
    if(is.na(as.numeric(input$price))){
      stop(safeError("input correct price field"))
    }else{
      return(c("Price:",input$price))
    }
  })                          
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Rmarkdowncode:

````
---
title: ""
output: html_document
date: '2022-03-23'
---

```{r echo=FALSE, results = 'asis'}
cat("Trade Date:",format(Sys.Date(), format="%d-%m-%Y"))```
````

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this. We could make a reactive value:
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
date: '2022-03-28'
runtime: shiny
---

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(shiny)
```


```{r eruptions, echo=FALSE}
textInput("price","Price:", value = "", placeholder = "00.0")
     
  
output_price <- reactive ({
  if (is.na(input$price)) {
    stop(safeError("input correct price field"))
  } else{
    return(c("Price:", input$price))
  }
})

```


```{r echo=FALSE, results = 'asis'}
cat("Trade Date:",format(Sys.Date(), format="%d-%m-%Y"))
renderText(output_price())
```
````

[image]

Comment: (Message 1/2) To give a little bit of context, I am working on two different documents. The first is a shiny web app, where the user will select the inputs, the second is a rmarkdown, where the input of the user will be returned in a pdf doc (that will be downloadable from the UI). I would like to have the user select the input in the UI, the input is then "elaborated" in the server or in rmarkdown ( - I don't care), and then returned in the rmarkdown pdf document. I do not want to have the input in the rmarkdown but just the result of the if statement.

Comment: (Message 2/2) I can return in the Rmarkdown document inputs that are not linked with any if or for statement thanks to "cat(input$side)". However, this function does not work when the input linked to any statement

Comment: Update: adding "return((output_price())" and removing the input line in the rmarkdown, I get the output I want. Nevertheless, the output is in the form [1] "Price:" "1000". How can I get just Price: 1000? results = 'asis' in the r chunk is not helping.